# Make a SharePoint Azure VM accessible over the internet

Tags: azure, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2016 server built in Azure.

The server has an public IP address of 13.74.185.68 and a DNS name of termsetsp2016.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

I can RDP to this address but not ping it.

I would like to use the DNS address to connect to the root SharePoint site over the internet (80).

Here is what I tried:

(1) Added an inbound security rule to permit Port 80 traffic in the Azure manager

(2) Added a binding in IIS  (SharePoint 80 to the external DNS name)

(3) Added a AAM for the Internet zone pointing to the external DNS name

http://termsetsp2016  Default http://termsetsp2016 
http://termsetsp2016.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com  Internet http://termsetsp2016.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

This isn't working (it just times out).  Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciate.

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: Hi Brendan, did you ever find out how to get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't support ICMP inbound traffic. Just tcp/udp.

Comment: Ended up using cloudshare.com instead of Azure as the public IPs are configured in their templates.